# Open Cart - PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::escape() in /home/l/beta4/system/library/db.php on line 24

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

I Changed my domain and hosting and I moved all the code from the first host to another with a database. Now, I'm getting an error in open-cart 1.5.6

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::escape() in /home/l/beta4/system/library/db.php on line 24

My hosting is Godaddy.

And here is my db.php code

```
<?php
class DB {
 private $driver;

 public function __construct($driver, $hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
  $file = DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php';

  if (file_exists($file)) {
   require_once($file);

   $class = 'DB' . $driver;

   $this->driver = new $driver($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
  } else {
   exit('Error: Could not load database driver type ' . $driver . '!');
  }
 }

 public function query($sql) {
  return $this->driver->query($sql);
 }

 public function escape($value) {
  return $this->driver->escape($value);
 }

 public function countAffected() {
  return $this->driver->countAffected();
 }

 public function getLastId() {
  return $this->driver->getLastId();
 }
}
?>
```

and line number 24 code is

> public function escape($value) {   return
>   $this->driver->escape($value);  }

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php, mysqli does not provide a function called "escape". There's the real_escape_string that could do the work though.

Answer (score 2):

You either updated Opencart, changed your DB driver or both.  You should make sure you include details like that in your question.

The DB class has a bug in 1.5.6 - Change the line that reads:

```
$this->driver = new $driver($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

to

```
$this->driver = new $class($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

Also, you should replace the mysqli driver **system/database/mysqli.php** with the version from 1.5.6.4 which can be downloaded [here](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/download/download&download_id=36) or after:

```
$this->link->set_charset("utf8");
```

add

```
$this->link->query("SET SQL_MODE = ''");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Open Cart 1.5.6 doesn't really support mysqli?
Not sure.

I used MySQLiz module to work around that problem:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=13041

Comment: It's because you're using a several-year old version of opencart, and those functionalities were meant for much older versions of php (ie: php 5.2). Something you may want to consider security-wise or update-wide if you want to keep your store up to standards. What that extension does is simply act as a work-around on some of the later versions of PHP to just make it work (it appears to be only up to 5.5 stated there since the last update was over a year ago). What PHP version are you currently using?